# Account total reputation did not increased

Tags: support, bug

My rep was 207. yesterday I edit a post and got 2 rep ...  still my total rep 207 instead of 209..

I think it's bug ... would someone review my account what is happened

**Notification Image**

[image]

**Total Rep Image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you also lost 2 reputation from [this suggested edit](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/53757) as [the corresponding question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/65425/is-zina-forgiven) has now been deleted, probably by [an automated process](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). These reputation losses don't appear in your reputation inbox.

Answer (score 1):

The system doesn't typically notify users when they *lose* reputation, only when they gain it.

So far as I can see, you recently lost two reputation due to a deleted post:

[image: post was removed]

This appears to be due to an edit which you suggested in the past: It was accepted, which gave you two reputation, but when the question was deleted any reputation associated with it was also revoked. No fault of your own, that's just how the system's cookies crumble sometimes.